# Retrieving page title from master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, page-title

To manage the page title on my pages, I have a master page with a ContentPlaceHolder in the header.

```
<head runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="headContent">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

On each of my pages, I add the meta tags and page title as follow:

```
<asp:content id="Header" contentplaceholderid="headContent" runat="server">
    <meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2" />   
    <meta name="description" content="page description" />
    <%Page.Title = "My page title";%>  
</asp:content>
```

I cannot modify the code on the pages by placing the `Page.Title` in the `OnInit` method of the page.

I need access to the page title in the codebehind of the master page, but I always get an empty title when I use `Page.Title`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `<%Page.Title = "My page title";%>` you *implicitly tell* the ASP.NET to execute this [embedded code block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx) during the page's render phase.

What does it mean? You won't be able to get this value before the page's render phase. Assuming you're trying to get this value a little bit earlier than during the render. That's why you get the empty string.

The workaround could be in setting your `Title` property of the `<%@ Page` directive in the beginning of your page e.g.:

```
<%@ Page Title="My Title Goes Here" Language="C#" ... %>
```

By setting this you'll be able to access the `Page.Title` property from your master page a little bit earlier than the page's rendering occurs.

Answer (score -2):

Just use

```
<title>My page title</title>
```

Comment: By using this construction you'll set the page's title, but you won't be able to get this value back through `Page.Title` property